# The equation$(x^2+y^2)^3-3(x^2+y^2)-2=0$defines the var$y$as a function of$x$,$y=f(x)$,in the vecinity of the point$(x,y)=(1,1)$Find$f'(1)$and$f''(1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this solved problem and I don't quite understand something, either it's a mistake or I'm missing something. So the problem is:
The equation $(x^2+y^2)^3-3(x^2+y^2)-2=0$ defines the variable $y$ as a function of $x$, $y=f(x)$, in the vecinity of the point $(x,y)=(1,1)$. Find $f'(1)$ and $f''(1)$.
The solution:
$3(x^2+f(x)^2)^2(2x+2f'(x)f(x))-3(2x+2f'(x)f(x))=0$
$3(1+1)^2(2+2)-3(2+2f'(x))=0$
$48-6-6f'(x)=0$
$f'(x)=\frac {42}6 \to f'(1)=7$
What I don't understand is why does the first $f'(x)$ dissapear? Is it just a mistake or am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a mistake. There's no reason that term should disappear.